# Audio mp3 progress bar which returns to zero after click

Tags: javascript, php, progress-bar, mp3, html5-audio

I am using the **new audio** object to make an mp3 player in javascript.

I have a progress bar that works fine on Mozilla Firefox. But the click does not work on edge and google chrome.

When I click on the progress bar, the sound goes back to zero, and so does the progress bar.

**JS**

```
audio.progress.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
         
    // calculate the normalized position clicked
    let clickPosition = (e.pageX  - this.offsetLeft) / this.offsetWidth
    let clickTime = clickPosition * audio.player.duration

    // move the playhead to the correct position
    audio.player.currentTime = clickTime
})
```

What happens is that the value of audio.palyer.currentTime does not change. When I click on the progress bar, it goes back to 0.

It's very strange, I have no problem on mozilla firefox.

Here are the headers:

**PHP**

```
if(file_exists($file_name)) {
    header('Content-type: audio/mpeg, audio/x-mpeg, audio/x-mpeg-3, audio/mpeg3');
    header('Content-length: ' . filesize($file_name));
    header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="'.$file_name.'"');
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary"); 
    header('X-Pad: avoid browser bug');
    header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
                
    readfile($file_name);
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You'll need to support range headers in your script.

Comment: Yes thank you that's it.